# SQLite - How to count row excluding row having the same values of a specific column

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, count, where-clause

Have have a table named: `assembly`

Columns:

```
id: number
partId: number
index: number
```

For an assembly, I have part with an index: 1,2,3.

But I can replace the part at the index 2, so I have 2 parts with the same index:

```
id partId   index
1  234      1
1  456      2
1  789      2
1  765      3
```

My assembly is the part 234, 456 OR 789, 765.

I need to know how many parts is in my assembly ( 3 parts )

I tried:

`select count(assembly.index)  from assembly where assembly.id in (1) group by assembly_id`

I get: 4

Ok it's normal.

I thought by grouping the indexes, I will get the real count:

I tried:

`select count(assembly.index)  from assembly where assembly.id in (1) group by assembly.id and assembly.index`

I get 2 rows with a count of 2

I was expected to get a one row with a count of 3.

Also, if I change the where statement to get the count of many assemble like

```
where assembly.id in (1,2,3)
```

I get one row per assembly with a wrong count.

Does anyone know how can I get the exact count?

Thanks

Comment: I don't get it.  If you have three indexes for an assembly doesn't that mean that 3 products are needed?  Why are only two given for your example?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select count(distinct a.index) no_indexes
from assembly a
where a.id = 1
```

This gives you one row, with a count of 3.

If you want one record per `id`, then:

```
select a.id, count(distinct a.index) no_indexes
from assembly a
group by id
```

Side note: `index` is a reserved word in all sql dialects, hence not a good pick for a column name.

Comment: You are right with the index, thanks a lot, it works now!